recomposition happen even when i use @Immutable
i have written the following code to test out @@Immutable , i had previously given a list of strings as a param to
forY

but even thouhgh the parameters don't change it recompose , i tried to  use @Immutable to avoid this but it's not working , can someone please tell me what i did wrong
@Immutable
data class MyUsersList(val l : List<String>)

class TEST : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            KdoumaScoreTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Log.d("TEST", "$innerPadding")

                    val x = remember {
                        mutableStateOf(1)
                    }

                    val y = remember {
                        mutableStateOf(1)
                    }

                    val yi = remember {
                        mutableStateOf(MyUsersList(listOf("a")))
                    }


                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    ){
                    forX(xx = x.value)
                    forY(yy = y.value,yi.value.l)

                        Button(onClick = {x.value ++}, modifier = Modifier.padding(50.dp)) {
                            Text("hi")
                        }
                    }





                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun forX(xx : Int){

    Toast.makeText(GlobalContextForRessources.getAppContext(), "xx", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Text("int $xx")

}

@Composable
fun forY(yy : Int,array: List<String>){

    Toast.makeText(GlobalContextForRessources.getAppContext(), "yy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Text("int $yy")

    for (one in array){
        Text(one)
    }
}



i tried also @stable but same output, as long as i click on the button both widgets recompose

mistake on my end  , the composbale function should recive the warpper stable class not the list inside it
